# Jquery Deferred/ variable is done immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4DAfn/290/) shows my code. I have three functions. functionB returns a user input. The time, the user needs for input, is not known. The problem is, functionA doens't wait and fires

```
 $.when(def1).done(functionC);
```

immediately. It must wait, until functionB has answered, no matter how long it takes. So there should be "User Input" alerted, instead of "undefined". How can it be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't return deffered object properly. You should return deferred object to operate it in `when()` function, and resolve it after a few seconds.

```
function functionB() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function () {
        deferred.resolveWith(this, ["User Input"]);
    }, 5000);
    return deferred;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4DAfn/295/

Comment: Great events often come from little causes. Thanks a lot.